# Rename the Globals Tab

Tags: user-interface

I'm only using Globals for the editable site footer content. Explaining to the user they need to look in "Globals" is a minor thing, but one extra step toward making a system less user friendly. If I can rename the tab to Footer it'll be a lot easier for the user to find by themselves.

I don't want to mess with the Craft build itself as I like to keep it up to date. Any ideas, is this something I can do with a plugin?

Comment: I've found a combination of [Craft's Static Translation](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/static-translations) and the [Control Panel Nav](https://github.com/engram-design/CPNav) allows me to hide and rename tabs. It will hopefully have removed a little bit of confusion with users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup! The [Control Panel Nav](https://github.com/engram-design/CPNav) plugin is exactly what you're looking for.

It allows you to easily rename, rearrange, or hide any of your tabs. It also lets you create additional custom tabs, using any URL you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use Craft's static translation support (which will rename it anywhere in the control panel) to rename it or something like the handy [CP CSS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss) plugin just to target that tab and rename it.